# How to compare two text files by column and output the number of times the columns match

Tags: perl

I have two tab-delimited genome sequence files (SAM format), and I would like to compare them to see how many times certain sequencing reads (which comprise a single line) are present in each.

Here is an example of input file format:

```
HWI-AT555:86:D0:6:2208:13551:55125       122     chr1    77028   255     94M555N7M       *       0       0       GTGCCTTCCAATTTTGTGAGTGGAGNACAAGTTCGCTAAAGCTAATGAATGATCTACCACCATGATTGAGTGTCTGAGTCGAATCAAGTGAATTGCTGTTAG   &&&(((((*****++++++++++++!!&)*++++)+++++++++++++++++++++++++*++++++++*****((((((''''''&&&&'''&&&&&&&&   NM:i:3  XS:A:+    NH:i:1
```

The important part is the sequence read id, which is the first column (ie HWI-....55125). This is what I want to use to compare the two files so that I can count the number of duplicates/copies.

Here is what I have so far:

```
unless (@ARGV == 2) {
    print "Use as follows: perl program.pl in1.file in2.file\n";
    die;
}

my $in1 = $ARGV[0];
my $in2 = $ARGV[1];

open ONE, $in1;
open TWO, $in2;

my %hash1;
my @hit;    

while (<ONE>){
    chomp;
    my @hit = split(/\t/, $_);
    $hash1{$hit[0]}=1;
}
close ONE;

my @col;

while (<TWO>){
    chomp;
    my @col = split(/\t/, $_);
    if ($col[0] =~ /^H/){  #only valid sequence read lines start with "H"
        print "$col[0]\n" if defined($hash1{$_});   

    }
}
close TWO;
```

So far it looks for a match in hash1 while going through the second file line by line and prints out any matches. What I would like it to do is count how many times it finds a match and then print out the number of times that happens for each sequence id and a total number of matches.

I am new to programming and I am quite stuck with how I can keep a count when there are matches while going through a loop. Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if I didn't make something clear enough.

Comment: Are you asking how to keep track of how many of the `$col[0]` values matches? How about incrementing your hash? E.g. `if (defined $hash{$col[0]}) { $hash{$col[0]}++ }` (I assume you meant `$col[0]` as the hash key, and not `$_` which is the entire line.)

Comment: Not sure if you have posted the complete code, add `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the start of your script

Comment: You're right, I didn't include the use warnings/strict, but I do have it in my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your `%hash1` with zeros instead of ones:

```
while (<ONE>){
    chomp;
    my @hit = split(/\t/, $_);
    # Start them as "0" for "no duplicates".
    $hash1{$hit[0]} = 0;
}
```

Then, in your second loop, you can increment `$hash1{$col[0]}`:

```
while (<TWO>){
    chomp;
    my @col = split(/\t/, $_);
    # Increment the counter if %hash1 has what we're looking for.
    ++$hash1{$col[0]} if(exists($hash1{$col[0]}));
}
```

There's no need to check `$col[0] =~ /^H/` since `%hash1` will only have entries for valid sequences, so you can just do an [`exists`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html) check on the hash. And you want to look at `$hash1{$col[0]}` rather than `$hash1{$_}` since you're only storing the first part of the lines in your first loop, `$_` will have the whole line. Furthermore, if you're just grabbing the first field of each line you don't need the [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) calls but they do no harm so you can keep them if you want.

This leaves you with the all the repeated entries in `%hash1` as entries with non-zero values and you can [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) those out:

```
my @dups = grep { $hash1{$_} > 0 } keys %hash1;
```

And then display them with their counts:

```
for my $k (sort @dups) {
    print "$k\t$hash1{$k}\n";
}
```

You could also check the counts while displaying the matches:

```
for my $k (sort keys %hash1) {
    print "$k\t$hash1{$k}\n" if($hash1{$k} > 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mu, it works great. I just made one modification in order to count up the total number of matches taking place, by counting up the $hash1{$k} in the for loop: `for my $k (sort @dups) {
 $sum += $hash1{$k};
 print OUT "$k\t$hash1{$k}\n";
}
print "Total matches = $sum \n";`